# image width and height problem in mobile devices

Tags: html, css

so i have my header design which looks like this(**see image below**)

[header design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXtFl.png)

so everything is working fine the desktop version of the website, but i have problems in mobile version. The images are not responsive. Basically i want to convert the header design into working code. Please help !

**Code**

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#img{
    position: absolute;
    right: 100;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 30%;
}


#img2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 100;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 10em;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 30%;
}
<header>
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 10em;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8  my-auto mt-3 mb-5">
                <h2 style="font-weight: bolder;margin-top: 2em;margin-left:1em;font-size: 7vw;font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;" data-sal="slide-up" style="margin-left: 1.5em;" data-sal-delay="1500" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bouce" data-sal-duration="1200"><span class="mb-5">Capture your</span><br><span>priceless</span><br><span>moments</span><br><span>with aw zone</span></h2>     
                </div>
                <div id="img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1024613/pexels-photo-1024613.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="300" class="thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div id="img2">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1024613/pexels-photo-1024613.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="300">
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile version you have to insert **Media Queries** into you CSS. Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) you will find your answer for sure. Just add Media Queries into your CSS code.